# I'm trying to find a way to print the body of an external URL. I can already get the title printed correctly

Tags: javascript, android, printing, webview

I've extracted most of the parts from my original code to give you an idea of how its working so far. I've managed to get it pulling in the webview title but would also like to get it to display more of the HTML content or source code as I'm trying to print to a small thermal printer to allow me to print a reciept.

```
   webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");

        --------------------------------------------------

          btnPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        printData();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

       --------------------------------------------------

               @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1)
        void printData() throws IOException {

            try {
                String msg = webview.getTitle();
                msg+="\n";
                outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
                lblPrinterName.setText("Printing Text...");

            } catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend WebViewClient and override shouldOverrideUrlLoading.
create a class:

```
    private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient{

    public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading  (WebView  view, String  urlConection){
        URL aURL = new URL(url); 
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
        conn.connect(); 
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        String htmlContent = readInputStream(is);
        printHtmlContent(htmlContent);
    }

    public String readInputStream(InputStream inputStream){
       StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
       String line;
       try {
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             string.append(linea + "\n");
          }
       } catch (IOException e) {}
       return string.toString();
    }
}
    //

    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: Thank you for you help so far. I'm new to this type of code for creating apps. Do I need to put this code inside of my MainActivity or create a completely new Class as in a new page? I can display my full code if this would help you understand my layout? Or if you could advise me where to insert it into my current code please, that would help.  I look forward to your reply.

Comment: You can just create MyWebClient  inside MainActivity as an inner class.